# Terminology for web app running on hardware

Tags: terminology

I am trying to investigate how to develop an UI application that will run directly on hardware.  This will be very much like when you access the web based application within your router.

I don't really know how what keywords and terminology to use so that i can search tutorials on the net.

Can anybody give me the correct terms?  If you have tutorial suggestions, they are welcome as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Embedded** may be the term you are looking for.

Comment: software that runs directly on hardware (no OS) is often called firmware
My impression is that a lot of the fancy embedded stuff these days is usually a embedded version of linux with custom app on top...

Comment: looking into this i found a sub section in wiki called "embedded HTTP server".  this seems like that i need!  But tutorials are scarce making me believe there are other terms used for it. I'm more used to win apps, this is different for me...

Answer (score 1):

**Appliance** is another term along with Yagoo's embedded.  Typically hardware appliances run full stacks including LAMP.

Answer (score 1):

Many appliances are based off of stripped down Linux or FreeBSD kernels running Apache or a lightweight httpd.

There are actually specific Linux distributions that are tuned for this. Google "linux appliance distribution" and "small linux distribution"

Be advised, if it is commercial, Linux and the GNU stack may present an issue you must deal with, depending on how it is modified. FreeBSD does not have this license limitation.